# Session ID vs Port number

Tags: transport-protocol

How does the session ID differ from the port number? at the Application layer, Port Number Identifies the service, same for session layer. right? and these port numbers are assigned at Transport layer. Please explain in detail.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Network Engineering. Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this on [su].

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

TCP does not use session IDs, IP+port is the session identifier:

> TCP packets do not include a session identifier, both endpoints identify the session using the client's address and port

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

So I will assume that you mean session ID on application layer? As the name implies, session IDs are being handled by specific application that are running on it. There is no correlation between port number and session ID.

Let's take an example. You might open a website in your browser. The browser connected to the web server on port 80, because port 80 is the default port for web server. This is what is happening at transport layer. But at the application layer, the website is using for example PHP to create interactive website, so you can log in to it. And PHP on the server is keeping some kind of session ID in servers' temporary files, after you created session (i.e. logged into website).

Different applications (SMTP servers, web servers with PHP or other language, SSH service) have their own way of keeping sessions, and while standard services like mail, www, ftp and SSH have default ports that the server is listening on, session IDs are created for example randomly per session and have nothing to do with networking ports.

If you meant something different than session IDs in applications, then please elaborate.

//EDIT: but I can see that this questions has been blocked since it does not fit networkengineering stack exchange. Sorry for answering it if it's a problem.